# Multi-Queue (MQ) in SCSI and iSCSI

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scsi, iscsi, block-device

I have a question regarding **multi-queue (MQ)** in **SCSI** layer and consequently **iSCSI**. Apparently there is good technical and scientific literature explaining multi-queue (MQ) on block layer level. But there is rarely any good explanation that how this multi-queue (MQ) is triggered down to SCSI layer and then iSCSI. AFAIK, since Linux kernel 3.13 (2014), the linux block layer has multi-queue a.k.a **mq-blk**. After **mq-blk** in block layer, the **SCSI** IO submission path had to be updated. As a result, SCSI multi-queue a.k.a **scsi-mq** work has been functional since Linux kernel 3.17. Therefore, I have following questions:

**Question 1:** How actually multi-queuing is achieved in SCSI layer?

**Question 2:** Traditionally, the SCSI mid-level layer used to create **queuecommand ()**. Now when there is multi-queuing implemented in SCSI, does multi-queuing actually means creating more than one **queuecommand ()**?

**Question 3:** Where exactly one can see multi-queue in SCSI code base?

**Question 4:** Once we have multi-queue in SCSI, how is this implemented in iSCSI level?

Please help me understand it.